# Please Explain This Piece of Code

Tags: c++

So I have been attempting to split a string in C++ and dump the contents into a vector. I found an answer to the problem so I copied the solution and started playing around with it to understand it but it still appears to be very cryptic. I have the following snippet of code which is a mix of stuff I made and copied material. I have commented every line that I understand the purpose of. Could someone fill in the remaining comments (basically explaining what they do). I would like to fully understand how this is solved.

```
ifstream inputfile; //declare file
inputfile.open("inputfile.txt"); //open file for input
string m; //declare string
getline(inputfile, m); //take first line from file and insert into string

std::stringstream ss(m);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
std::vector<std::string> vstrings(begin, end);
std::copy(vstrings.begin(), vstrings.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

while(true) //delay the cmd applet from closing
{
}
```

Comment: `//delay the cmd applet from closing` Yikes! Your program has no business doing this. Configure your terminal not to close when your program has finished running; it is not your program's job to do this. It is not part of your program's semantics. (Hint: `cmd` has a `/K` switch)

Comment: Get a book on C++ or something like it and learn the language and its standard library.

Comment: let me look into that, but while we're on this topic (i'm new to c++ so i'm trying to learn as much as I can) wouldn't this while(true) be a relatively safe way of accomplishing the task? The same way that an OS has a background infinite loop that runs and searches for requests, this program has a while loop that continues indefinitely, say I were to add a condition if input = "Exit" (string input << cin) then would this be a good way of handling that job?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the on-line documentation available for [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/), [`istream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/), [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) etc?

Comment: I just have this copy of Algorithms of C that my family had laying around,and I have the pdf from cpp.com

Comment: This is an awful way to break a string down into fields.  It's simple to write, but it lacks any form of flexibility, and uses a lot more resources than necessary.

Comment: @Useless no, thanks for the links, let me explore

Comment: @James Kanze how should it be broken down? I found no straightforward way of just indexing a string until a particular delimiter is found. I would have opted to use a for loop or while loop and done it that way if it was possible. Do you know how to make that work in c++ by any chance?

Comment: @JamesKanze - IIRC, There is this code or very similar code in the C++PL 3E in the 1st chapter or one of the early chapters. I had learnt C++ from the 2nd Edition (pre STL). And looking at this code in the 3rd Edition made me buy the 3E and get familiar with the STL - of course all this was more than 10 years back.

Comment: For _indexing a string until a particular delimiter is found_ just use `std::string::find_first_of` et al (the old `strchr` from `<cstring>` is ok too, but I'd avoid `strtok`)

Comment: The `std::string` class has a number of search functions, but in
general, it's best to stick with the iterators: `std::find` and
`std::find_if` are great for finding the pivots (where you want
to break), and you can construct a new string from two
iterators.  This makes it simple to use a functional object with
a regular expression, for example (which you can't do with the
string member functions).

Comment: Why was this closed after it has been concluded? This would be an excellent resource for other people as confused as I was

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** Real code should never contain annotations to the degree that I'm about to employ. (It should also not be so doggamned cryptic.)*

I've added a function body and the necessary headers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   // Construct a file stream object
   ifstream inputfile;

   // Open a file
   inputfile.open("inputfile.txt");

   // Construct a string object
   string m;

   // Read first line of file into the string
   getline(inputfile, m);



   // Copy the string into a stringstream so that we can
   // make use of iostreams' formatting abilities
   std::stringstream ss(m);

   // Construct an iterator pair. One is set to the start
   // of the stringstream; the other is "singular", i.e.
   // default-constructed, and isn't set anywhere. This
   // is sort of equivalent to the "null character" you
   // look for in C-style strings
   std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
   std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;

   // Construct a vector by iterating through the text
   // in the stringstream; by default, this extracts space-
   // delimited tokens one at a time. The result is a vector
   // of single words
   std::vector<std::string> vstrings(begin, end);

   // Again using iterators (albeit un-named ones, obtained
   // with .begin() and .end()), stream the contents of the
   // vector to STDOUT. Equivalent to looping through `vstrings`
   // and doing `std::cout << *it << "\n"` for each one
   std::copy(
      vstrings.begin(),
      vstrings.end(),
      std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
   );

   // Blocks the application until it is forcibly terminated.
   // Used because Windows, by default, under some circumstances,
   // will close your terminal after the process ends, before you 
   // can read its output. However: THIS IS NOT YOUR PROGRAM'S
   // JOB! Configure your terminal instead.
   while (true) {}
}
```

Suffice it to say, this is *not* an optimal way to print to console, newline-separated, each token found on the first line of a text file on disk. Please do not copy code verbatim from the internet and expect the Red Sea to part.

Comment: Also, the while(true){} loop is a room heater.  Fix your terminal or, at least, put a sleep call in the loop.

Comment: +1 for not being a just a commenter and taking time to explain.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: You are welcome. (Don't get used to it!)

Comment: @frogeyedpeas. You can also use `system("pause")` or `std::cin.get()` to keep the terminal up.

Comment: @MartinJames http://thedailywtf.com/Comments/Just-a-WarmUp.aspx

Comment: +1 for a perfect biblical reference.